# Rails unrelated tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I  have client table that references a country table. When inserting a client, countries are provided to the user in a dropdown thus inserting an id of the country in the client table. How do you display the name of the country instead of Id on client show page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with select tags and a database table, I always find it better to use collection_select http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select

you can use

```
collection_select :client, :country_id, Country.all, :id, :name
```

Comment: I have no problem displaying the drop down, I want to display a name instead of an id in the show page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have the associations set up similar to below, in which case you can just reference the country name through the association `@client.country.name` rather than `@client.country_id` (I'm making some assumptions about variables and field names here).

Associations would be set up as follows:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :country

  ...

end


class Country < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :client

  ...

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like...

```
<%= select_tag 'country_id', options_from_collection_for_select(@countries, 'id', 'name') %>
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag

Per your comment below, the easiest way to get words in the url is overriding to params in the mode, with something like this:

```
def to_param
  "#{id}-#{name}".parameterize
end
```

But that isn't perfect and instill includes a number. To get rid of the number you're going to create a unique string, typically called a slug, and then do all your finding by the slug.

Comment: I have no problem displaying the drop down, I want to display a name instead of an id in the show page.

Comment: Added some basic code about adding a name to your url, think that's what your talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I put this and it seems to be working now. Is it the right solution?

```
<%= Country.find(@client.country_id).name %>
```

Comment: I added a method to my model since I realized I was going to need it in many places.